# Can't align number in accordion menu

Tags: html, css

HTML / CSS

I'm currently using this accordion menu on my demo site http://cssmenumaker.com/menu/flat-accordion-menu and I'm trying to align a number along side each heading, that I can link to a back end eventually.

I've included the screen shot below as you can see I cannot align it properly.

https://gyazo.com/b80a5e09f9de7e89b4d1bd20f5c1403a

I've tried to amend the display properties to inline / inline-block to no avail. If you need any other information, please let me know.

Thanks Guys.

I had tried the `<span>` before, but it wouldn't work it as it was outside the `<a>` tags, when I've moved it inside it works.

[jsfiddle available here](http://jsfiddle.net/tr0xpk1t)

Comment: Can you share your code? It would help to analyze your issue.

Comment: To be able to help you, we'll need to see your code. You can go to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to put together a working example for us to work with

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tr0xpk1t/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I think this can do it in several ways.the easiest way is to put
  `&nbsp;` between `Emails` and `20`.
- or else you can use email count inside `<span id="someid" style="margin-left:30px;">20</span>`.

**there are so many ways to do this.**